# ICE WLAN No Route to Host nach Update auf Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, hot-spot

My Dell E7470 is just running Ubuntu 22.04. Every place it's connecting to WLAN fine. But in the German ICE-trains it won't work anymore since I updated to 22.04

Comment: This is an English only site. The question must be in English.

Comment: Bara för att påpeka problemet andra spräk än Engelska; det fonns för många som hamnar utanför.

Answer (score 1):

I have a lenovo T520 and experience the same problem after updgrading to 22.04 LTS. I did try anything I could guess and try without access to internet but no success.

I got a connection to WiFionICE but no traffic. I suspect a problem with DHCP. Either no nameserver or wrong default gateway. Another guess is, that there may be a new policy in 22.04 which prevents connections to unencrypted WLAN networks.

Back home and at work today, everything works as usual. Obviously I have no ICE at home to do further debugging. Perhaps this may point somebody into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

on my last trip I manipulated settings for the WLAN. I then connected to the internet successfully. Unfortunately I had to exit before I could document the changes. May be this hint can help somebody? In any case I will check next time...